# Specified cast not valid on ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: vb.net, casting, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

When I run the code below in a virtual machine then I'm getting the following exception on the `.Get()` function: `Specified cast is not valid`

```
For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard").Get()
    If queryObj("SerialNumber") Is Nothing Then
        Return "" 'If nothing then return string.empty
    Else
        Return CStr(queryObj("SerialNumber"))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `return queryObj("SerialNumber")?.ToString()`. Note that `ManagementObject`/`ManagementBaseObject` are disposable. You need to call `queryObj.Dispose()` before returning a value or use a `try/finally` block or a `Using` statement.

Comment: You should also be specific: `ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard")`. A `For Each` loop is also not necessary, since it will return a single object. Get the `FirstOrDefault()` item: `(...) ManagementObjectSearcher(...).Get().OfType(Of ManagementBaseObject)().FirstOrDefault()` (check for null). With WMI queries, a `Try/Catch/Finally` block is mandatory.